# Perform addition like Row1+Row2,Row2+Row3 in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have data like this

```
Q_NAME  VALUE

    Q1_2018   100
    Q2_2018   200
    Q4_2017   300
    Q3_2017   150
```

I wanna add like  **Q2_2018+ Q1_2018, Q2_2018+Q4_2017**, how can I perform this addition

Expected results I wanted is like

```
Q_NAME          VALUE
Q1_2018+Q2_2018 300
Q2_2018_Q4_2017 500
```

Comment: Please try to better explain the logics behind your needed result. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note I am answering the question in the title of this post :

> Perform addition like Row1+Row2,Row2+Row3 in oracle

You can use analytic functions for this sort of thing.  The LEAD function can be used to pick data from a row further down the dataset.  In this example it looks at the next row (order by quarter):

```
WITH
 example_data (quarter, amount) AS
   (SELECT 'q1',1000 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'q2',2000 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'q3',3000 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'q4',4000 FROM dual 
   )
SELECT
 quarter
,amount
,LEAD(amount) OVER (ORDER BY quarter)             next_quarter
,amount + (LEAD(amount) OVER (ORDER BY quarter))  two_quarter_total
FROM
 example_data
;
    quarter amount  next_quarter   two_quarter_total
    q1      1000    2000           3000    
    q2      2000    3000           5000    
    q3      3000    4000           7000    
    q4      4000
```

The final row does not have a 'next' row so returns a NULL

Comment: Thanks, I  used LEAD I missed out this one "amount + (LEAD(amount) OVER (ORDER BY quarter))"

Answer (score 1):

Use PIVOT logic :

```
with t as ( select q_name, value from mytable )
select Q2_2018 + Q1_2018, Q2_2018 + Q4_2017 from t
pivot 
(
  max(value) for q_name in 
  ('Q1_2018' as Q1_2018,'Q2_2018' as Q2_2018, 'Q3_2017' as Q3_2017, 'Q4_2017' as Q4_2017)
);

Q2_2018+Q1_2018 Q2_2018+Q4_2017
--------------- ---------------
      300              500
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a055b/14)